# How to perform parallel execution on Cucumber with TestNG framework?

Tags: selenium, automation, cucumber, testng, appium-android

I have been trying to implement parallel execution in my automation framework. These are the solutions I tried to implement:

1.
`

```
@Override
    @DataProvider(parallel = true)
    public Object[][] scenarios() {
        return super.scenarios();
    }
```

`2.`

```
<test name="L2-Test">
        <parameter name="PortNumber" value="5723" />
        <classes>

            <!--            <class name="com.L1.androidrunner.ReRunTest"/>-->
            <class name="com.L2.androidrunner.L2_runner"/>
        </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test -->
    <test name="L2-Test1">
        <parameter name="PortNumber" value="4723" />
        <classes>
            <!--            <class name="com.L1.androidrunner.ReRunTest"/>-->
            <class name="com.L2.androidrunner.L2_runner"/>
        </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test -->
```

`

By implementing the above solutions, I'm able to launch the application on my emulator but the scenarios in the feature file are not getting executed. Please help me out on this!